# How to bind a collection of Shapes to a Path?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, graphics

I am trying to look this up but the results come up about the binding path, not `System.Windows.Shapes.Path`.

How can I bind it to an `ObservableCollection` of `Shapes`, either `Line`, `Rectance`, etc or `LineGeometry`, `RectangleGeometry`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [GeometryGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometrygroup.aspx), and bind it's `Children` to a [GeometryCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometrycollection.aspx).  This can then be set as the Path's `Data`.

Comment: Thanks Reed, would you do it like this? `    <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" Fill="Blue">
        <Path.Data>
            <GeometryGroup Children="{Binding Elements}">

            </GeometryGroup>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>`?

Comment: @Joan: That should work, provided "Elements" is defined as a GeometryCollection

Comment: Thanks Reed. It seems to work but when I added an EclipseGeometry to it, it doesn't appear. I set it's RadiusX and Y and Center, but couldn't find its color/stroke property. Do you know how to do this? Just trying to see my shapes on the GeometryCollection.

Comment: @Joan: You may need to raise PropertyChanged for Elements.  GeometryCollection doesn't implement INotifyCollectionChanged, so new items won't show up necessarily, I don't think.. (not 100% sure here...)

Comment: Thanks Reed, I also noticed that it was the binding or the update event because when I assign directly to its children in code, it shows up. Do you know how I can raise this event? Do I have to provide a backing field for it or do I have to write a type that encapsulates the GeometryCollection?

Comment: Actually Reed, it seems to me that it's the binding that might not be setup correctly but I am not getting any error printed to Output window about binding errors.